# How to check if data has arrived using firestoreConnect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux-firebase

I'm using the `firebaseConnect` HOC to bind my Firestore data to Redux.

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'my_collection', queryParams: ['orderByKey'] }
    ])
)(MyComponent)
```

It does the job, but the component that displays my data is empty until the data arrives. Is there any way to know if the data has been retrieved or not (query successful/failed if you will) with `firestoreConnect`?

Answer (score 1):

I found out how by reading the [docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/queries.html). You have to import `isLoaded` along with `firestoreConnect`. It tells if data has been loaded.

Example:

```
  if (!isLoaded(todos)) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
```